# min-height and max-height of container and relative height of child

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML, which consists of a paragraph within a div container:

```
<div><p>Paragraph of text...</p></div>
```

I am currently reading about adjusting the sizes of child elements relative to the size of the parent element. If, for example, I gave the div element a min-width and max-width of 300px and 500px, respectively, and the p element a width of 75%, then, as I adjust the browser window, the div element size adjusts accordingly, as does the p element, retaining its relationship to the div element. The CSS might be something like:

```
div {min-width:300px;
     max-width:500px;
     height:500px;
     background-color:Pink;}
p {width:75%;
   height:75%;
   background-color:rgb(0,20,80);}
```

This works fine. However, if I attempt the same with height, this behaviour doesn't occur; instead, the p element "squishes" down to the text size, as oppose to adjusting to 75% of the div element size. This only happens if I give min-height and max-height values; if, instead, I give just a fixed height value (as above), then the height of the p element is 75% of the div element, but it also means that there is not the "dynamic" behaviour that occurs: the height for both the div and p elements are fixed. The following is what I thought would be required, but doesn't seem to work:

```
div {min-width:300px;
     max-width:500px;
     min-height:300px;
     max-height:500px;
     background-color:Pink;}
p {width:75%;
   height:75%;
   background-color:rgb(0,20,80);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code to a plain html page and noticed that if I go up to the highest html tag, and basically to every parent tag up to the div, it works.

Can't say I'm 100% sure, but I guess that you have to relate to parent tag height, and if it's not defined then the behavior is not as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html, body { height:100%; /*Can also use 100vh*/ }

        div {
            min-width: 300px;
            max-width: 500px;
            min-height: 300px;
            max-height: 500px;
            background-color: Pink;
            height: 100%;
        }
        p {
            width: 75%;
            height: 75%;
            background-color: rgb(0,20,80);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>Paragraph of text...</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Karen, It does appear to need the two height:100% values for (html and body) and div. Not sure what these are doing...